# Обработка различных структур данных одной функцией

Tags: алгоритм, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, любой-язык

Есть функция, которая принимает массив чисел и находит в нем минимальное значение. Есть два массива с числами, один одномерный, второй двумерный. Можно ли как-то заставить принимать функцию оба вида этих массивов, чтобы не писать две реализации с разными аргументами?

Comment: в некоторых языках это из коробки идет

Comment: @Grundy меня интересует в первую очередь сам алгоритм. В Java, например, такого нет, если не ошибаюсь, и в с++, а если я буду знать алгоритм, то смогу реализовать его на любом языке.

Comment: Алгоритм чего? В зависимости от реализации двумерного массива - проход по нему может отличаться: в некоторых языках массив одним куском идет и нет разницы одномерный он или нет, в некоторых - двумерные массивы как массивы массивов рассматриваются - и обработка в них будет отличаться

Comment: Все действительно зависит от языка. В JS, например, это можно сделать вообще просто: `function min(arr) { return Math.min(...arr.flat())}`

Answer (score 1):

Вы задали очень абстрактный вопрос. Отказ от конкретного языка приведёт к абстрактному ответу. Общий подход заключается в том, чтобы реализовать итератор, который умеет проходить по одному и по второму массиву. В разных языках он может быть сделан по-разному. Я приведу два: python и golang.

Итератор -- это конструкция, которая позволяет перебрать элементы и на этом всё. Это выражается в действиях:

- Взять следующий
- Проверить последний ли был элемент
- Отдать текущий элемент

В языках со статической типизацией для решения этой проблемы используются интерфейсы. Это более идеоматичнее и приводит к меньшему количеству ошибок. Но это дольше реализовывать. Поэтому я начну с golang (статическая типизация).

## Golang

Такие действия в golang выражаются в интерфейсах. Интерфейс -- это контракт, который заключает между собой итератор (конкретная его реализация) и потребитель этого итератора, т.е. та функция, тот объект (кто-либо), кто использует этот итератор. От этого контракта нельзя отойти в сторону. Иначе будет ошибка. Выясняется это на этапе компиляции (Внимание, запомните это предложение).

```
type Iterator interface { 
    Current() *int
    IsFinish() bool
    Next() *int
}
```

Теперь, в коде Вы сможете объявить этот интерфейс как тип переменной и передавать туда объекты, у которых есть эти методы. Если у объекта нет одного из методов, либо они не на 100% похожи, то произойдёт ошибка. В этом суть статической типизации: её преимущество и недостаток.

**Ответ на вопрос**
Отметим, что реализаций этого интерфеса может быть сколь угодно много. В вашем случае -- реализаций будет две:

-- Для одномерного массива 
-- Для двумерного массива

```
func ExtractMin(i Iterator) *int {
    var minEl *int 
    for !i.isFinish() {
        el := i.Next()
        if el == nil {
            break
        }
        if minEl == nil || *minEl > *el {
            minEl = el
        }
    }
    return minEl
}
```

И в случае одномерного массива, и в случае двумерного массива Ваш код будет выглядет, как я привёл выше. Отличие будет лишь в том, что способ перебора, который реализует итератор, будет различным. Реализацию этого итератора я предлагаю Вам сделать самому, для тренировки на Вашем языке со статической типизацией.

## Python

Этот язык, в отличие от golang, обладает динамической типизацией. Именно поэтому в нём НЕТ интерфейсов. Иными словами, как указано в примере выше, вы могли бы вместо `Iterator` подставить всё, что угодно. Например, число или массив. Что захотелось, то и подставили. В python нет способа соблюсти контракт также изящно. Это и плюс и минус одновременно. Всё зависит от Ваших целей.

Здесь есть важное отличие от статической типизации. Все ошибки вы пойматете во время выполнения программы. Если Вы передали бы в функцию число, и интерпретатор (здесь НЕ компилятор) увидит это, то скажет вам об этом только тогда, когда дойдёт до строки, где ему не удалось корректно выполнить код. В данном случае, интерпретатор, например, мог бы не найти метод `Next` переменной `i`. Поэтому в `python` Вам придётся уделять много внимания тому, что и как Вы передаёте в функции и, по возможности, дополнительно проверять это с помощью мета-конструкций языка.

**Ответ на вопрос**

Покажем, код, который делает аналогичные действия:

```
def ExtractMin(i):
    minEl = None
    while not i.isFinish():
        el = i.Next()
        if el is None:
            break
        if minEl is None or minEl > el:
            minEl = el
    return minEl
```

В данном случае, качество реализации `i.Next()` оставляет желать лучшего, так как эта функция возвращает `None` в одном случае и число -- в другом. Так делать не стоит в python. Но для того, чтобы максимально точно показать отличия в подходах, я сделал именно так.

Answer (score 0):

```
// псевдо-код
X=[0]*7
Y=[[0]*7]*7 //static arrs

def accept_arr(arr:list):
 item_in_arr = 0
 item_is_elem =0 
 for row in range(7):
   item_in_arr=arr[row]
   if item_in_arr = type(int)
     // process
   else: // this is structure
     for elem i range(7):
      item_is_elem=arr[row][elem]
      // process
```